# How to run python in backend of flask web app?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

I'm building a web app using flask. I've made a completely separate python program and I want to run it in the backend of the web app. It is basically a program that takes in inputs and makes some calculations about scheduling and sends the user an email.

I don't know where or how to implement it into the web app.

Answer (score 0):

normally one would implement such a manner with a message queue to pass it to a backend or with a database to persist these calculation jobs for another backend program.

If you  want to stay with python flask is offering something for you called [Celery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/celery/)